# Taking screenshots with PIL

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I'm working on script that take screenshot every 1 min but there is one problem that when I save it gives me invalid argument and I don't know why that is.

Code:

```
from PIL import ImageGrab
from PIL import Image
import time
import datetime
import os

def screenShot():
    while True:
        try:
            date = str(datetime.date.today())
            hour=str(datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%H"))
            os.makedirs("D:/mine/" + date + "/" + hour)
        except OSError,e:
            if e.errno != 17:
                raise
            time.sleep(1)
            pass
        while True:
            date = str(datetime.date.today())
            hour = str(datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%H"))
            date_time = str(datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))
            img = ImageGrab.grab()
            FILES_DIR = 'mine'
            SAVE_PATH = "D:/"
            LOGFILE_NAME = "%s.png" % date_time
            LOGFILE_PATH = os.path.join(SAVE_PATH, FILES_DIR, LOGFILE_NAME)
            img.save(LOGFILE_PATH)
            break
        time.sleep(60)

screenShot()
```

This is the error I'm getting:

```
IOError: [Erno 22] Invalid argument: 'D:/mine\\2016-12-02 20:24:37.png'
```

I searched a lot and I found this code and it worked but I can't see different between this code and my code.

```
import os
import sys
import time
from PIL import ImageGrab
from PIL import Image
from os import environ
import random
n = -1
while True:
    n += 1
    # generate a random time between 120 and 300 sec
    random_time = random.randrange(1,2)
    # wait between 120 and 300 seconds (or between 2 and 5 minutes)
    print "Next picture in: %.2f minutes" % (float(random_time) / 60)
    time.sleep(random_time)
    img = ImageGrab.grab()
    FILES_DIR = 'mine'
    SAVE_PATH = "D:/"
    #SAVE_PATH = os.path.expanduser("~")    #It is cross-platform
    LOGFILE_NAME = "test{n:0>5}.png".format(n = n)
    LOGFILE_PATH = os.path.join(SAVE_PATH, FILES_DIR, LOGFILE_NAME)
    print LOGFILE_PATH
    img.save(LOGFILE_PATH)
```

I'm forgetting something but I don't know what is it.

Comment: You need to include the traceback. Without that, we have no idea what the issue is.

Comment: Why is it `'D:/'` when this seems to be on Windows? Does `r'D:\mine'` exist? Is `D:` at network drive that perchance does not allow `:` in filenames?

Comment: The code is creating illegal filenames. Filenames can't have `:` colon characters in them on Windows. You're going to have to change them to something legal, like `.` (periods).

Comment: @dhke i don't understand you

Comment: @martineau it is the drive letter i can't change it

Comment: Sorry, a colon after a drive letter is OK on Windows. I meant the colon characters is the time portion (`20:24:37`) of the filename argument. Try using `strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H.%M.%S")` to get rid of the offending ones.

Comment: @martineau you saved me  bro

Comment: You're welcome. Adding the error you were getting made it relatively easy to see what was wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure the `SAVE_PATH` and `FILES_DIR` are valid meaning they exist in your hard drive and the path should be absolute path. for example in linux it would be `~/D/mine` in your case it should be `D:\mine` instead of `D:/mine` also `strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")` should be `strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H.%M.%S")`

Comment: in linux it is very easy i never open windows but my friend needed that script so i helped him

Comment: I see,after all,`import os` should have handle that,,the problem was with the time formatting you had to put `.` instead of `:`,,windows sucks after all,no offense

Answer (score 1):

D:/mine\2016-12-02 20:24:37.png. You must have formatted something wrong if it has "/" and "\". And also, same as the other people: you can't create files with colons.

Comment: A new feature  in Python 3.9.0 was implemented in the datetime module which meant that colons ":" in the string format of any datetime objects were no longer used. Instead, hyphens are now used. This was done for the purpose of being compatible with most file systems and to prevent issues when using datetime strings in filenames. Windows does not allow the use of the colon as a part of its filename naming conventions.