# Take "screenshot" of application window/label in tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am working on some sort of animation maker with tkinter but I have run into a problem, i would want to save the current application window or canvas widget to a .png file for later use, is this possible? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Of course, just store the values with the variables somewhere and write a function to get them.

Comment: Not what i meant @Atlas435

Comment: Take a canvas widget and store the visual representation (What you see) as a .png .

Comment: You cant do it with tkinter. You may find something here:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846947/get-screenshot-on-windows-with-python

Comment: @chboo1 It is a good practice to accept/upvote the answer, if it was helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pyautogui
myScreenshot = pyautogui.screenshot()
myScreenshot.save(r'Path to save screenshot\filename.png')
```

And there it is ! ^^

And if you don't want everything else on your screen, you can try to crop it with pil

[How to crop an image using PIL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9983263/how-to-crop-an-image-using-pil)

Comment: If you use PIL, you could also take a screenshot with PIL.

Comment: @Atlas435 Related to your comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40938868/taking-screenshots-with-pil

Comment: That's right haha, I took the first method but why make it complicated when you can do simple ?

Comment: @TheMachinist Python says this:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "screenshot.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pyautogui
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyautogui'

Comment: If we have to install anything please tell me

Comment: thanks that works just fine for me `pip3 install pyautogui` made it install easy